# Extend home partition /home with additional HDD

Tags: 12.04, hard-drive, home-directory

I have two hdd installed where at the moment one sda* runs ubuntu 12.04 and sdb* runs ubuntu studio.

I want to add the complete sdb* hdd to my /home partition on sda*

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boot up from a [live gParted](http://gparted.org/livecd.php) and resize /home as described in the [manual](http://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual#gparted-resize-partition). From the manual:

- Select a partition. See the section called “[Selecting a Partition](http://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual#gparted-select-partition)”.
- Choose: Partition → Resize/Move. The application displays the Resize/Move /path-to-partition dialog.
- Adjust the size of the partition. See the section called “[Specifying Partition Size and Location](http://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual#gparted-specify-partition-size-and-location)”. 
  -Specify the alignment of the partition. See the section called “[Specifying Partition Alignment](http://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual#gparted-specify-partition-alignment)”.
- Click Resize/Move. The application displays the resize/move partition operation in the Pending Operations pane.
- Examine the operation that was added to the Pending Operations pane. 
   If the operation involves a move step, then consider the following:

  - A move step might take a long time to complete.
  - If the partition is an operating system boot partition, then a move step might cause the operating system to fail to boot.

  If you are not prepared to wait or to fix potential operating system boot problems, then you might want to undo the operation. See the section called “[Undoing Last Operation](http://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual#gparted-undo-last-operation)”.